# installing twilio in ubuntu in linux with terminal

Tags: python, linux, twilio

I am trying to install twilio in my Ubuntu 16.04LTS. however I am getting some error and was enable to import it. the command lines I inserted is the following along with the error:

```
trina@Trina-PC:~$ sudo easy_install twilio
[sudo] password for trina: 
Searching for twilio
Best match: twilio 6.4.1
Processing twilio-6.4.1-py2.7.egg
twilio 6.4.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio-6.4.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for twilio
Searching for cryptography>=1.3.4
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cryptography/
Best match: cryptography 1.9
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/2a/0c/31bd69469e90035381f0197b48bf71032991d9f07a7e444c311b4a23a3df/cryptography-1.9.tar.gz#md5=1529f12fb403c9a0045277cb73df766c
Processing cryptography-1.9.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-zvhL9Y/cryptography-1.9/setup.cfg
Running cryptography-1.9/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-zvhL9Y/cryptography-1.9/egg-dist-tmp-8YO7r3
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:434:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

can you please tell me what's going wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need to install `libffi-dev` and `libssl-dev` lib to fix this problem.
For Ubuntu user, run this command:

```
apt-get install libffi-dev libssl-dev
```

For Centos user, try this:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

Also you can try to install these dependencies, and then retry.

```
apt-get install python-openssl
apt-get install python-gmpy
apt-get install python-gmpy2
```